# Binding values from List<int> to Controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Suppose I have List myNumbers.
I have a set of Sliders, and I want to bind i.th Sliders value to myNumbers[i]. Int-s are not properties, so i cant bind to them.

Should I store my data in another way?

Is there another way to make the binding magic work?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand you problem? Do you want to decide with a slider which item from `myNumbers` is displayed? Do you have any code to show?

Comment: The key question here is:  Do you need two-way binding?  Or one-way?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you bind to the list as indexer like that
"{Binding Path=[i]}" 
where i is the index of the respective slider?

Comment: If I understand correctly, an int can't be the source of binding.

This is how I'm trying to do it, but it doesn't work.

 Binding myBind= new Binding();
                myBind.Path = new PropertyPath(e.menetrend[i]);                
                mySlider.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, myBind);*/

Comment: You do it wrong.  You should write: myBind.Path = new PropertyPath(String.Format ("[{0}]", i)); 
Of course, the DataContext should be set to e.menetrend.